# How can I make the character jump?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse and I've tried several codes to make the character jump and nothing seems to work, it just cancels out the falling and left and right keys, I don't care what key is used to make it jump, just any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
    package com.firstgame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Ac extends JPanel implements Runnable {
public Rectangle floor;
public Rectangle character; 

public int keyRight = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
public int keyLeft = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;

public int floorheight = 80;
public int fps = 1000;
public int characterheight = 36; 
public int characterwidth = 24;
public int fallingFrame = 0;
public int fallingSpeed = 1;
public int movementFallingSpeed = 5;
public int movementResetSpeed = 1;
public int movementSpeed = 1;
public int movementFrame = 1;
public int noseHeight = 10;
public int noseWidth = 10;

public boolean objectDefine = false;
public boolean falling = false;
public boolean running = true;
public boolean left = false;
public boolean right = false;
public boolean leftNose = true;
public boolean rightNose = true;


public Thread game;
public Ac (Ad f) {
    setBackground(Color.blue);

    defineObjects();

    game = new Thread(this);
    game.start();   

    f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == keyLeft) {
                left = true;
                rightNose = false;
                leftNose = true;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == keyRight) {
                right = true;
                leftNose = false;
                rightNose = true;
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == keyLeft) {
                left = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == keyRight) {
                right = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

void defineObjects() {
    character = new Rectangle ((Am.width/2) - (characterwidth/2), (Am.height/2) - (characterheight/2), characterwidth, characterheight);
    floor = new Rectangle(0, 300, 600, 100);

    objectDefine = true;

    System.out.println("Shapes DefineObjects is running");

    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if (objectDefine) {
        System.out.println("Graphics is running");
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(floor.x, floor.y, floor.width, floor.height);

        if(leftNose) {
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillRect(character.x - noseWidth, character.y + (character.height/4), noseWidth, noseHeight);
        } else if(rightNose) {
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillRect(character.x + character.width, character.y + (character.height/4), noseWidth, noseHeight);
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {

        //character feet
        Point pt1 = new Point(character.x, character.y + character.height);
        Point pt2 = new Point(character.x +character.width, character.y +character.height);


        //Falling
        if(fallingFrame >= fallingSpeed) {
            if (floor.contains(pt1) || floor.contains(pt2)) {
            falling = false;
            } else {
                character.y += 1;
                falling = true;
            }

            if (falling) {
                character.y += 1;
            }

            fallingFrame = 0;
        }else {
            fallingFrame += 1;
        }   
            //movement speed check
        if(falling) {
            movementSpeed = movementFallingSpeed;
        } else {
            movementSpeed = movementResetSpeed; 
        }

        //Movement
        if(movementFrame >= movementSpeed) {
            if(right) {
            character.x += 1;
        }

        if(left) {
            character.x -= 1;
        }

        movementFrame = -1;
        } else {
        movementFrame += 1;
    }

    fpsSetter();

    repaint(); 

    System.out.println("Run Method is running");
    }
}
public void fpsSetter() {
try{
    game.sleep(fps/1000);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("fpsSetter is running");

}
 }
}
```

Comment: Try taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493809/how-to-make-sprite-jump-in-java/16494178#16494178)

Comment: You should use `javax.swing.Timer` insteead of `sleep()`

Comment: Also, shouldn't you repaint after changing the values in the key listener?  can't run your code, seems to be missing some other dependent code. So I can only guess.